# cp: cannot stat permission denied

Tags: cp

I have a file called fileArc.c and I was given instructions for an assignment that if I do the command

`cp fileArc.c /pc`

that this file would then be accessible in a created folder on my desktop. However when I try using the command I get

`cp: cannot stat '/pc/fileArc.c': Permission denied`

I am not sure what to do to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure the command was exactly `cp fileArc.c /pc`? Maybe there was `~` or `.` in front of the slash `/` character. Please recheck as this would be important

Answer (score 2):

`/pc` is not a casual directory on Unix system. Users directories are generally in home user directories (`/home/…/`), you can also write on `/tmp` and some others destinations (mounted drives in `media`…)

Then the first copy should fail if the `/pc` directory doesn’t exist and you have no right on `/`. If you are root, the copy will succeed, but if there is no `/pc` directory, the copy will copy your file renamed `/pc` : not what you have intended to do.

You can have an idea of the permission of `/pc` and its content with the command `ls -la /pc`

Answer (score 0):

like said above this is probably permissions of your folder /pc .
if it is not created yet, this is about your user permissions, if it is created already, probably the best is to change the folder permissions.